# Metodologia de escrita CSS usando \: no nome da classe ( Tailwind CSS )

Tags: css, css3, metodologia, w3c, tailwind

Eu sei que existe um infinidade de frameworks CSS (Bootstrap, Materialize, Skeleton, Bulma, Foundation), assim como uma infinidade de metodologias para se escrever CSS (BEM, DRY, ITCSS, OOCSS)

Mas eu estava dando uma investiga no raw do CSS do **Tailwind** ( https://tailwindcss.com/ ) e vi algumas classes escritas como abaixo

```
.focus\:placeholder-gray-500:focus:-ms-input-placeholder{
  color:#a0aec0!important
}

.xl\:w-9\/12 {
  width: 75%
}

.xl\:hover\:shadow-lg:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.05)
}
```

Assumo que fiquei um pouco confuso, porque alguém ira escrever CSS dessa forma? Isso é uma nova metodologia?

Eu não achei uma forma muito pratica de escrever CSS, mas teria algum motivo técnico por traz que justifique se escrever CSS assim?

E é seguro escrever `.classe\:modificador { }` ou algum interpretador de CSS pode não reconhecer esse `\:` ou `\/` no meio de um nome de classe no CSS?

Aqui tem um exemplo prático

```css
.div\:border\/900 {
  border: 10px solid #000;
}
.focus\:bg-red:focus {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div:border/900">
  <input type="text" class="focus:bg-red">
</div>
```

Comment: Não vou elaborar uma resposta pois essa facilidade foi removida da recomendação mas nessa versão depreciada do CSS3 , https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/, informa que que essa sintaxe `\:` éra tratada como uma sequencia de escape para `:` e sua finalidade foi de atribuir seletores a namespaces exemplo: O estilo cujo o seletor fosse `html\:h1` seria aplicado a elementos `h1` cujo namespace é `html`, `<html:h1>`. Nos outros caso é apenas um `:` escapado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado pela dica e pelo link ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O escape é usado a anos, mas na maioria dos casos é **desnecessário**, se você pode escrever algo mais simples separado por hífen (`-`) ou por underscore (`_`) pra que apelar para algo assim?

Então quase todo mundo que faz um trabalho decente faz algo simples, limpo e eficiente, mas ai surgem esses novos frameworks/kits/libs/métodologias querendo reinventar a roda, assim como quando vieram com o tal BEM (Block Element Modifier), que é uma solução para resolver problemas que as próprias pessoas criaram e por fim seus projetos andam com os problemas e remendo (BEM) de mãos dadas ao invés de fazer de uma forma bem pensada.

O escape era para a necessidade de usar um caractere que era limitado para X situação, imagine você ter um HTML especifico, do qual os IDs eram populados dinamicamente e você não tem controle sobre isto, algo como:

```
<div id="#900"></div>
```

Não é possivel fazer isto:

```
##900 {

}
```

Claro que até poderia usar `[id="#900"]`, mas só para exemplificar mesmo, você também poderia escapar assim:

```css
#\#900 {
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<div id="#900">teste</div>
```

Note que também ocorrem situações aonde você quer fazer o "match" com uma classe use `:`, você poderia simular assim:

```css
[class="foo:bar"], /*exato*/
[class^="foo:bar "], /*começa*/
[class*=" foo:bar "], /*contêm no meio de duas outras classe*/
[class*=" foo:bar$"] /*termina*/
{
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo:bar">exato</div>
<div class="foo:bar ">começa</div>
<div class="foo:bar abc">começa</div>
<div class="abc foo:bar def">contêm no meio de duas outras classe</div>
<div class=" foo:bar">termina</div>
<div class="abc foo:bar">termina</div>
```

Veja a complexidade desnecessária, fora 4 seletores em uma unica regra, para tentar chegar ao efeito do que `.class` faz, agora usando o escape simplificou:

```css
.foo\:bar {
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo:bar">exato</div>
<div class="foo:bar ">começa</div>
<div class="foo:bar abc">começa</div>
<div class="abc foo:bar def">contêm no meio de duas outras classe</div>
<div class=" foo:bar">termina</div>
<div class="abc foo:bar">termina</div>
```

Vale notar, o que você já deve saber, que `:` é usado em pseudo-elementos e pseudo-class, então vou resumir e deixar bem evidente o que entendo disto tudo:

> **O `\:` não é uma metodologia**

Se alguém pegar "X" e resolver começar a usar para um caso especifico eles podem até inventar uma tal metodologia, mas isso nem quer dizer que é bom, só quer dizer que as pessoas gostaram e para elas foi pratico e que vai ter gente que vai adotar a nova técnica só porque todos outros estão usando e porque lhes parece legal, não estão adotando porque é melhor.

---

### Respondendo:

> Assumo que fiquei um pouco confuso, porque alguém ira escrever CSS dessa forma? Isso é uma nova metodologia?

É uma nova metodologia, o motivo, porque ele "querem", como descrevi no resto da resposta, nada melhora, é só uma maneira que eles querem fazer e tem gente que quer seguir sem ter motivação real ou utilidade real.

> Eu não achei uma forma muito pratica de escrever CSS, mas teria algum motivo técnico por traz que justifique se escrever CSS assim?

Isso é caso de opinião, mas na pratica na pratica mesmo, todo mundo anda exagerando com CSS, a maioria das coisas poderiam ser simples e CSS já **não** é muito bem feito, tem problemas, se inventar demais já estraga de vez, e é o que esses "frameworks" estão fazendo, querendo reinventar a roda e dizer que o deles é melhor, eu trabalho com HTML+CSS desde o CSS2.1 (Internet Explorer 6) e sempre consegui criar CSS simples mas que o site ficava ótimo, com efeitos razoáveis e fáceis de entender, não há justificativas reais para inventar métodologias assim, só se for questão de "marketing", atrair o tolos que entendem pouco e que querem o fácil.

> E é seguro escrever .classe:modificador { } ou algum interpretador de CSS pode não reconhecer esse : ou / no meio de um nome de classe no CSS?

É sim seguro, desde que saiba o que está fazendo, somente interpretadores antigos CSS poderiam sofrer com problemas, navegadores modernos suportam a anos o escape, como eu disse no começo da resposta. Mas vale lembrar que além de escapar os caracteres você pode também usar algo como `.foo\3Abar` (hexadecimal, `3A` é o mesmo que `00003A`) que equivale ao `.foo\:bar`, o único motivo para se usar isto é que navegadores mais antigos que o IE8, como IE6 e 7 não reconheciam o `\:`, dentre outros problemas que talvez eu liste depois (se é que alguém se interessa pelo que ocorre no Internet Explorer).

> mas teria algum motivo técnico por traz que justifique se escrever CSS assim?

Não, a não ser que vá desenvolver para um "framework" ou projeto que já use tal estrutura, e por vez se usar outra forma diferente da escolhida pelo "projeto" ai sim teria um problema, então se seguir o que eles estabeleceram como "regra" é o que facilita no ambiente, justamente porque "eles estabeleceram", não quer dizer que vá ser melhor fora de projetos que já usem isso.

Na maioria das vezes não passa de exagero quando estabelecem que vão usar algo.

Comment: Valeu a resposta Guilherme, está bem completa e esclarecedora!

Comment: Guilherme vou deixar esse link comentado aqui pq achei ele bem interessante e tem alguns detalhes a mais sobre o que eles chamariam de `Utility First` https://blog.codecasts.com.br/conhecendo-css-utility-first-com-tailwind-css-55f81b65f9e4 entre outras coisas seria um "CSS sem herança", achei que valia a pena deixar o link registrado aqui