# CSS: Passar valores/parametros através dos nomes de classes

Tags: css, sass, less, stylus

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de informar valores através de nome de classes para ser usados como valores nas propriedades das mesmas. Exemplo:

```css
.text-(color) {
color: (color);
}
```

O resultado seria:

```css
.text-blue {
color: blue;
}
```

Eu li sobre pré-processadores, eu nunca havia utilizado, mas até então não encontrei nada que se refira a solução dessa dúvida. Somente uma solução parecida que ainda não é suportada por nenhum navegador:
https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/#article-header-id-2

Comment: Olha esse metodologia de escrever CSS `<input type="text" class="focus:bg-red">` aqui nesse link tem mais detalhes https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/432733/metodologia-de-escrita-css-usando-no-nome-da-classe-tailwind-css

Answer (score 6):

Com CSS puro vc pode fazer usando custom variables, não é exatamente como vc quer mas pode te ajudar

Caso queira uma cor especial  para o `:hover`, basta no `:root` vc tb declarar uma cor que vai usar no `:hover`, no caso a `var(--red)`, e no `p.azul:hover` vc muda o valor de `--azul` para `var(--red)`

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor:

```css
:root {
  --azul: blue;
  --red: red; /* cor do hover */
}

p.azul {
  color: var(--azul);
}

p.azul:hover {
  --azul: var(--red); /* muda a var Azul para ser a var da cor do Hover */
}
```

```html
<p>lorem lorem</p>
<p class="azul">lorem lorem 1</p>
<p class="azul">lorem lorem 2</p>
```

Comment: Putz legal isso aí hein, não conhecia.

Comment: @LeAndrade bem massa né, e eh nativo do CSS, não precisa compilar, e já tem um bom suporte dos browsers

Comment: Boa, muito bom também não conhecia. Mas se eu quiser informar o nome da cor dinamicamente? Tipo o nome que houver na classe assumir o valor da propriedade color? Era isso que gostaria de saber.

Comment: @RodrigoAlves veja a edição e os comments que deixei no código da resposta. Como falei essa é uma abordagem com CSS puro

Comment: Encontrei uma solução parecida mas que ainda não é suportada por nenhum navegador:  https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/#article-header-id-2

Comment: @RodrigoAlves na verdade da uma olhada aqui, certamente vai te interessar! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330390/existe-alguma-forma-de-usar-um-custom-attribute-como-valor-de-uma-propriedade

Comment: valeu @hugocsl, obrigado pela alternativa!

Comment: @RodrigoAlves sem problemas meu caro